# Drawing barChart from downloaded data

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

Here's my problem. I'm trying to draw a chart from data that I'm downloading from API. To dowload data I use `OTTO` and `Retrofit` library. For drawing chart I'm using `MPAndroidChart`. In `MagnitudeFrequencyChart` I'm preparing data to create on chart. When I'm implementing downloaded data to a constructor and creating chart method in `onServerEvent` I get info that my chart has no data avaible. Is it possible to create barChart outside `OnCreateView` method? Or how can I implement my downloaded data to `OnCreateView`?

```
public class GraphFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;
    private BarChart barChart;
    private Bus bus = BusProvider.getInstance();
    private MagnitudeFrequencyChart magnitudeFrequencyChart;
    private List<Feature> features;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph, container, false);
        barChart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.barChart_magnitudeFrequency);

        return view;
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onServerEvent(ServerEvent serverEvent) {

        features = serverEvent.getDataResponse().getFeatures();
        magnitudeFrequencyChart = new MagnitudeFrequencyChart(features, barChart);
        magnitudeFrequencyChart.getMagnitudeFrequencyChart();

    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onErrorEvent(ErrorEvent errorEvent) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + errorEvent.getErrorMsg(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        bus.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        bus.unregister(this);
    }
}
```

Class where I'm creating a chart:

```
public class MagnitudeFrequencyChart {

    private List<Feature> features;
    private BarChart barChart;

    public MagnitudeFrequencyChart(List<Feature> features, BarChart barChart) {
        this.features = features;
        this.barChart = barChart;
    }

    public void getMagnitudeFrequencyChart() {

        int mag3 = 0;
        int mag4 = 0;
        int mag5 = 0;
        int mag6 = 0;
        int mag7 = 0;
        int mag8 = 0;
        int mag9 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < features.size(); i++) {

            double magnitude = features.get(i).getProperties().getMag();

            if (magnitude >= 3 && magnitude <= 3.99) {
                mag3++;
            } else if (magnitude >= 4 && magnitude <= 4.99) {
                mag4++;
            } else if (magnitude >= 5 && magnitude <= 5.99) {
                mag5++;
            } else if (magnitude >= 6 && magnitude <= 6.99) {
                mag6++;
            } else if (magnitude >= 7 && magnitude <= 7.99) {
                mag7++;
            } else if (magnitude >= 8 && magnitude <= 8.99) {
                mag8++;
            } else if (magnitude >= 9 && magnitude <= 9.99) {
                mag9++;
            }
        }

        ArrayList<BarEntry> yData = new ArrayList<>();
        yData.add(new BarEntry(mag4, 0));
        yData.add(new BarEntry(mag5, 1));
        yData.add(new BarEntry(mag6, 2));
        yData.add(new BarEntry(mag7, 3));
        yData.add(new BarEntry(mag8, 4));
        yData.add(new BarEntry(mag9, 5));

        String xValues[] = {"4.0+", "5.0+", "6.0+", "7.0+", "8.0+", "9.0+"};

        ArrayList<String> xData = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < xValues.length; i++) {
            xData.add(xValues[i]);
        }

        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(yData, "Chart");
        barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarData data = new BarData(xData, barDataSet);
        barChart.setData(data);
        barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
        barChart.animateY(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to create a bar chart from data that I'm earlier downloaded

Comment: You can keep the reference List<Feature> in a singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to use `findViewById()` on the BarChart inside the `onCreateView()` method.

I think what you really want to do is hide the chart until the data has arrived from the server. If that is the case, all you need to do is:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph, container, false);
    barChart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.barChart_magnitudeFrequency);
    barChart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return view;
}
```

then inside `getMagnitudeFrequencyChart()`:

```
    BarData data = new BarData(xData, barDataSet);
    barChart.setData(data);
    barChart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
    barChart.animateY(2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't working. Somehow when I'm creating serverEvent, barChart isn't getting the downloaded data.

Comment: @Dominik is the `onServerEvent` getting triggered?

Comment: @Dominik also check you are getting a non-empty list